# Install Windows on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, mac

I would like to install Windows XP on Mac OS X. Following are my quests related to this..

Do I need to have the activation of Windows XP or just licensed one is enough to install using either of the way using Boot Camp or Virtual Box from Sun.

Answer (score 7):

Installing windows on a mac using Boot Camp or virtualbox is just like installing windows on a normal, physical PC with regards to licensing.

So you need a licensed product key and you need to activate the installation just like on any other PC.